# Google places API returning results that don't match the keyword

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I'm using the Google Places API to find Mexican restaurants in a given area by passing "Mexican" or "mexican+restaurant" as a keyword. Usually the first couple hits are Mexican Restaurants but then after that there will often be some incorrect results. For example, searching

"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=[KEY]&type=restaurant&keyword=mexican&radius=16090&location=43.48,-72.33"

gives Burger King as one of the results. If I change the keyword to "mexican+restaurant," the results include some Asian restaurants.

My guess is that the keyword matching is too generous (maybe it's returning these because some review compared them to Mexican restaurants?). So is there a way to make the matching more strict? Alternatively, is there a way to extract cuisine categories from the API so I can manually remove the false hits?

Update: I've found the Yelp API is much better suited to my purposes. I'm still curious about the answer to this question, but for anyone with a similar issue, try Yelp instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the same issue has already been reported in Google issue tracker. Have a look at this bug:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64621302

I would suggest adding your comment with examples of your requests in this bug and star the issue to subscribe to the notifications.